# How to preserve DOCTYPE declarations when manipulating xml with Jsoup

Tags: java, xml, jsoup, doctype

I have a XML document which starts the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE  viewdef [
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;"> <!-- no-break space = non-breaking space U+00A0 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY copy   "&#169;"> <!-- copyright sign, U+00A9 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY amp    "&#038;"> <!-- ampersand -->
<!ENTITY shy    "&#173;"> <!-- soft hyphen -->
]>
```

I am parsing the document with Jsoup 1.8.2 in the following way:

```
public static void convertXml(String inFile, String outFile) throws Exception {
    String xmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(inFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(xmlString, "UTF-8", Parser.xmlParser());
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(outFile), document.html(), "UTF-8");           
}
```

I expect the output file to be the same as the input in this case, but Jsoup generates this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE viewdef> 
<!-- no-break space = non-breaking space U+00A0 ISOnum --> 
<!--ENTITY copy   "&#169;"--> 
<!-- copyright sign, U+00A9 ISOnum --> 
<!--ENTITY amp    "&#038;"--> 
<!-- ampersand --> 
<!--ENTITY shy    "&#173;"--> 
<!-- soft hyphen --> ]&gt;
```

Is this a bug or is there any way to preserve the original DOCTYPE declaration?

Answer (score 0):

> Before parsing `xmlString` with Jsoup, replace the DOCTYPE sequence manually with something then add it back in the final document.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
private final static String DOCTYPE_SEQUENCE = "<doctype-sequence/>";
private final static Pattern patern = Pattern.compile("(?i)<!DOCTYPE[\s\S]+]>");

public static void convertXml(String inFile, String outFile) throws Exception {
    String xmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(inFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
    
    // * Remove the doctype sequence if found
    String doctype = "";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        doctype = matcher.group(0);
        xmlString = xmlString.replace( doctype, DOCTYPE_SEQUENCE);
    }

    // * 
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(xmlString, "UTF-8", Parser.xmlParser());
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(outFile), document.html().replace(DOCTYPE_SEQUENCE, doctype), "UTF-8");           
}
```

The `pattern` variable is outside of `convertXml` for avoiding multiple pattern compilation.